# Are the Fourier coefficients of a new form real?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f\in S^\text{new}_k(Γ_0(N))$ be a $\text{newform}$ . Are all its Fourier coefficients real? Of course the Hecke operators $T_n$ are selfadjoint for $(n,N)=1$, but is it also true for all $n$?